# Is freak of nature an oxymoron?

Tags: grammar, literary-techniques, literary-device, oxymoron

My question is, is the term "freak of nature" a oxymoron?

I feel as if it is a oxymoron due to freak and nature being contradictions of each other, but I am not sure.

Comment: Now that I think about it, I think it's a paradox because it is more than two words.

Comment: It's a simple description.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not contradictory, because what it means is a deviation from or perversion of nature - something that has suddenly become unnatural.